# Getting (selecting) CAT Object for given bone with MaxScript

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I have an CAT hierarchy and an selected bone:
[image]

I want to select the CAT Object that is related to it (the "triangle" on screen).

I know I can go from given bone to root bone via parents this way:

```
local firstBoneName = (skinOps.GetBoneName (ePoly.modifiers[#skin]) 1 0)
local boneParent = getNodeByName firstBoneName 
while (boneParent.parent != undefined) do (
    boneParent = (boneParent.parent)
)
```

So now I have this (the root bone that has **no parent**):
[image]

But I want to select this:
[image]

How can I go **from one to another**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, when you already have the boneParent:

```
root = for obj in (getClassInstances CATParent) where obj.rootHub.node == boneParent do exit with obj.node
```